# Python мультипоточный парсер через Tor

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tor, lock, threading

Здраствуйте.
Пытаюсь написать мультипоточный парсер, который использует Tor, со сменой IP Tor прокси на лету. url сайта поставил другой, здесь это абсолютно не важно и никак не влияет на логику работы.
В функции start_all() создается Pool потоков, каждый из которых в функции start_thread() генерирует по еще одному additional Pool-у потоков. Этот additional Pool потоков использует один и тот же тор прокси.
Проблема в том что при возникновении исключения в функции get_data(), когда перестает работать Tor прокси на порту additional Pool-а, блокировка срабатывает сразу у нескольких потоков из этого Pool-а и они начинают одновременно пытаться менять Tor прокси мешая друг другу. Подскажите как организовать блокировку, чтобы во время срабатывания исключения, только один из потоков additional Poola   занимался сменой прокси, остальные в это время ждали и запускались только по команде, когда прокси сменился?
Переменная proxies выглядит в виде списка словарей:

```
proxies = [
            {'port': 0000, 'pid': 0000, 'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:0000', 'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:0000'},
            {'port': 1111, 'pid': 1111, 'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1111', 'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1111'},
            {'port': 2222, 'pid': 2222, 'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:2222', 'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:2222'},
        ]
```

Код:

```
import json
import requests
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
import threading
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import sys
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import tor_socks
from config import *


report = {}
proxies = []
lock = threading.Lock()
event = threading.Event()


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
register_logger(log_file=log_path)

ua_obj = UserAgent()


def end(mess):
    logger.warning(mess)
    tor_socks.kill_tor_all()
    sys.exit()


def load_report():
    global report
    if os.path.exists(main_path + 'report.txt'):
        with open(main_path + 'report.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            report = json.loads(f.read())
    else:
        report = {
            'total_count': 0,
            'search_count': 0,
            'empty_count': 0,
            'proxy_change': 0,
        }


def save_report():
    global report
    with open(main_path + 'report.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as w:
        w.write(json.dumps(report))


def check_internet():
    try:
        try:
            requests.get('https://www.google.com')
        except requests.ConnectTimeout:
            requests.get('http://1.1.1.1')
        return True
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return False


def change_proxy(main_thread):
    tor_socks.kill_pid(proxies[main_thread]['pid'])
    new_proxy = tor_socks.do_one_sock(proxies[main_thread]['port'])
    if not new_proxy:
        max_port = sorted(proxies, key=lambda k: (k['port']))[-1]['port']
        port = max_port + 1
        while not new_proxy:
            new_proxy = tor_socks.do_one_sock(port)
            port += 1
    proxies[main_thread] = new_proxy


def get_data(main_thread, additional_thread):
    global report, killer, event
    try:
        event.wait()
        headers = {'User-Agent': ua_obj.random}
        url = "http://httpbin.org/ip"
        res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies[main_thread], headers=headers).json()
        return res
    except Exception as e:
        event.clear()
        logger.warning(f'[{main_thread}-{additional_thread}] clear')
        logger.warning(f'[{main_thread}-{additional_thread}] {e}')
        while True:
            change_proxy(main_thread)
            logger.warning(f"[{main_thread} {proxies[main_thread]['port']}] proxy ip changed")
            report['proxy_change'] += 1
            sleep(randint(2, 3))
            break
        logger.warning(f'[{main_thread}-{additional_thread}] set')
        event.set()
        return 'error'


def check(main_thread, additional_thread):
    global report
    data = 'error'
    num_error = 0
    while data == 'error':
        data = get_data(main_thread, additional_thread)
        num_error += 1
        if num_error >= 5:
            end('num errors >= 5')
    with lock:
        print(f"[{main_thread}-{additional_thread} {proxies[main_thread]['port']}] {data}")
        report['total_count'] += 1
        if data:
            with open('results.txt', 'a') as w:
                w.write(data + "\n")
            report['search_count'] += 1
        else:
            report['empty_count'] += 1
        if not report['total_count'] % 1000:
            save_report()
            logger.warning(report)


def start_thread(main_thread):
    event.set()
    while True:
        pool = Pool(requests_per_thread)
        for additional_thread in range(requests_per_thread):
            pool.apply_async(check, (main_thread, additional_thread))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()


def start_all():
    pool = Pool(threads)
    for main_thread in range(threads):
        pool.apply_async(start_thread, (main_thread,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.warning(f'#### start with threads {threads * requests_per_thread} {threads}/{requests_per_thread} ####')
    if check_internet():
        load_report()
        proxies = tor_socks.do_socks(num=threads)
        if len(proxies) < threads:
            end('num proxies != num threads')
        start_all()
    else:
        print("Network Error")
    logger.warning('end')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сделать две вещи. Во-первых, нужно захватить блокировку, чтоб смену прокси делал только один поток, а остальные не могли сделать этого одновременно.

Во-вторых, нужно чтобы поток знал с каким прокси он работал когда случилась ошибка, и не пытался его поменять, если это сделал уже какой-то другой поток раньше (пока этот ждал блокировку). Для этого можно в `change_proxy` передавать тот прокси, который использовался, и смотреть, если уже сконфигурирован другой, но менять прокси не нужно (кто-то уже это сделал).

```
proxies = []
proxies_locks = []

...

def change_proxy(main_thread, current_proxy):
    with proxies_locks[main_thread]:
        if proxies[main_thread] != current_proxy:
            return
        tor_socks.kill_pid(proxies[main_thread]['pid'])
        new_proxy = tor_socks.do_one_sock(proxies[main_thread]['port'])
        if not new_proxy:
            max_port = sorted(proxies, key=lambda k: (k['port']))[-1]['port']
            port = max_port + 1
            while not new_proxy:
                new_proxy = tor_socks.do_one_sock(port)
                port += 1
        proxies[main_thread] = new_proxy


def get_data(main_thread, additional_thread):
    global report, killer, event
    try:
        event.wait()
        headers = {'User-Agent': ua_obj.random}
        url = "http://httpbin.org/ip"
        current_proxy = proxies[main_thread]
        res = requests.get(url, proxies=current_proxy, headers=headers).json()
        return res
    except Exception as e:
        event.clear()
        logger.warning(f'[{main_thread}-{additional_thread}] clear')
        logger.warning(f'[{main_thread}-{additional_thread}] {e}')
        while True:
            change_proxy(main_thread, current_proxy)
            # логирование и посчет количества нужно перенести в change_proxy
            logger.warning(f"[{main_thread} {proxies[main_thread]['port']}] proxy ip changed")
            report['proxy_change'] += 1
            sleep(randint(2, 3))
            break
        logger.warning(f'[{main_thread}-{additional_thread}] set')
        event.set()
        return 'error'
...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.warning(f'#### start with threads {threads * requests_per_thread} {threads}/{requests_per_thread} ####')
    if check_internet():
        load_report()
        proxies = tor_socks.do_socks(num=threads)
        if len(proxies) < threads:
            end('num proxies != num threads')
        proxies_locks = [Lock() for _ in range(threads)]        ​
        start_all()
    else:
        print("Network Error")
    logger.warning('end')
```

Comment: Я как бы и спрашиваю как это сделать в коде.

Comment: Ваш код не походит. Я написал в описании что additional Pool работает все время с одним и тем же прокси, который определяется как proxies['main_thread']. Т.е. все Tor прокси всегда остаются неизменным 127.0.0.1:port_1, 127.0.0.1:port_2 и т.д., узнать что какой-то из них перестал работать можно только если произойдет exception в get_data()

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на изменения, которые я сделал по сравнению с вашим оригинальным кодом в вопросе. Они демонстрируют, где и какие изменения нужно сделать. Ясное дело, что я не тестировал и не запускал это все. Суть ваших возражений в комментарии я не понимаю, суть изменений как раз в том, как в `get_data` обрабатывается смена прокси, а именно чтоб разные потоки не делали это одновременно и только один это сделал. Если вам непонятно, как это делается задайте конкретный вопрос о том, что непонятно - я внесу уточнения или дополню ответ.

Comment: Мне все понятно. Внимательно посмотрите код. Я специально его здесь запостил почти весь. Суть в том, что строка `if proxies[main_thread] != current_proxy: `  функции `change_proxy()` не имеет смысла т.к. `proxies[main_thread]` всегда равен `current_proxy`. Сам прокси не меняется, происходит перезапуск tor прокси на этом же ip адресе 127.0.0.1 и порту. Проблема в том что event.clear() срабатывает сразу на нескольких потоках и меня интересует вопрос как этого избежать?

Comment: `tor_socks.do_one_sock(proxies[main_thread]['port'])` не возвращает новый объект? зачем тогда присваивание `proxies[main_thread] = new_proxy`? если такая проверка не годится, то тогда сделайте другую (по `id(current_proxy)` или явно храните версию конфигурации и увеличивайте ее на один при каждой смене). Этот код - демонстрация идеи. Нужно проверить тот ли самый это прокси или уже измененный. Как конкретно это делать - вам лучше знать.

Comment: присваивание `proxies[main_thread] = new_proxy` сделано из-за того, что если не получится освободить этот же порт, то tor прокси будет создан на другом, свободном  порту

Comment: Вы так и не ответили объект при этом будет новый или нет? Вы пишете, что `proxies[main_thread] всегда равен current_proxy`, но если один из потоков уже выполнил `proxies[main_thread] = new_proxy`, то другой ждущий уже увидит новое значение в `proxies[main_thread]` (отличное от `current_proxy`). Кроме, конечно, случая если в `new_proxy` будет точно тот же объект, т.е. если `tor_socks.do_one_sock(proxies[main_thread]['port'])` всегда возвращает `proxies[main_thread]`. Но если он возвращает тот же объект, то и смысла в присваивании нет.

Comment: может быть тот же объект и может быть новый